# Deleting single row from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying to delete a single row from the database based on it's ID. A user should be able to click the delete button and everything in that row should be deleted - based on the code i have below, it kinda works, but it deletes all rows from the table as opposed to just the one specific row based on the ID.

I appreciate any code you see may not be best practice, but this is simply in basic testing phase for a personal project for me to better learn PHP.

What am i doing wrong?

```
try {
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM property_details ORDER BY id ASC");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
    exit;
}

$property = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<table><th> Property Name </th><th> Description </th><th> Host Name </th><th> Location </th><th> Price </th>';
foreach ($property as $property_details) {
$id = $property_details['id'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['property_name'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['property_description'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['host_name'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['location'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo "&#163;" . $property_details['price'] . " per night";
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="deleteItem" value="DELETE ID '.$id.'" />';
    echo '</td></tr>';

    if(isset($_POST['deleteItem'])) {
    try {
            $results = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM 
                                property_details
                        WHERE
                    id = :theid
                        ");
        $results->bindParam(':theid', $id);
        $results->execute();
        } 

    catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Could not insert data in to the database";
    }   
    }
    } 

echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Either (1) have a form per button, with a hidden input with the id or (2) add the id in the name somewhere there (`name="deleteItem['.$id.']" ` is a good start.

Comment: This would probably be easier with a jQuery trigger of a POST or DELETE call than throwing in a form for each button.

Comment: @Wrikken if i were to use option 2, how would i proceed with that? How would i incorporate that in to my code?

Comment: @tadman Could you help direct me in the right direction if i were to use jQuery to do this?

Comment: This is about as basic as jQuery gets, so what you need is a jQuery tutorial of some sort. The [main site](http://jquery.com/) has a lot of material to start with.

Comment: Seems to be a basic php script that is mixing out the input and output of a form. You are putting out the form by looping through all the properties. For each one you save the unique id. In the loop you also check if the deleteItem button has been pressed and if so delete the item you are looping round, irrespective of whether the current id is the one they clicked to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Crude way of sorting out the processing.

This takes the calue of deleteItem, explodes it out based on space and uses the 3rd item as the id of the item to delete:-

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['deleteItem'])) 
{
    list($filler, $filler2, $id_to_delete) = explode(' ', $_POST['deleteItem']);
    if (is_numeric($id_to_delete))
    {
        try 
        {
            $results = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM 
                                        property_details
                                        WHERE
                                        id = :theid
                                        ");
            $results->bindParam(':theid', (int)$id_to_delete);
            $results->execute();
        } 

        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo "Could not delete data from the database";
        } 
    }   
}

try 
{
    $results = $db->query("SELECT id, property_name, property_description, host_name, location, price FROM property_details ORDER BY id ASC");
} catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
    exit;
}

$property = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<table><th> Property Name </th><th> Description </th><th> Host Name </th><th> Location </th><th> Price </th>';
foreach ($property as $property_details) 
{
    $id = $property_details['id'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['property_name'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['property_description'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['host_name'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $property_details['location'] . '<br />';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo "&#163;" . $property_details['price'] . " per night";
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="deleteItem" value="DELETE ID '.$id.'" />';
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';

?>
```

Probably should check that 3rd part is a valid item to delete (ie, valid id)